# Using lodash for grouping data

Tags: lodash

There is an array of JS objects. Object has the following attributes:

- year
- name
- salary

The array is sorted by (year + name). It is given what there are only 2 different values in "name" attribute.

The goal is to generate another JS array, sorted by year, containing objects with 2 attributes only:

- year
- 100 * (salary for name#1) / (salary for name#2)

If one of the salaries does not exists or 0 for given year then the object shell not be created for this year.

I tried to use _lodash (I am not sure this is the right tool for this):

```
var groupByYear =_.groupby(myArray, function(element){
    return element.year;
};

return _.map(groupByYear, function(el){
  if (el.size() == 2 and el[0].salary > 0 and el[1].salary > 0)
     return { "year": el[0].year , "percent": 100 * el[0].salary / el[1].salary };
}
```

but I am not confident this is right approach; for example the intermediate array named groupByYear is created.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you provide sample input data and sample output.

Comment: Please input complete example input and complete example output

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
_.chain(arr)
  .groupBy('year')
  .map((salary, year) => [year, 100 * salary[0].salary / salary[1].salary])
  .sortBy('0')
  .value()
```